# STM32F7: Route I2C3 (clock and data) to I2C1 in software?

Tags: stm32, i2c

This is for STM32CubeIDE on windows 11.

I have a [STM32F746G-DISCOVERY kit](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f746gdiscovery.html#overview) (with display) that has a [WM8994 (Audio Hub CODEC)](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8994_Rev4.6.pdf) connected to I2C3 for control. I'm learning how to generate a sound from the STM32F746G. I extracted the driver for the WM8994 from a sample project and I managed to clean up the code and run the initialization funcion...without any compile or run errors. But now that I was checking the display, the touch panel doesn't work. The touch panel for this board also uses I2C3.

I want to connect my scope and see what's going on on the I2C3 bus lines (clock and data) but this board does not bring those lines to a connector or any testpoints. I could solder a couple of wires to the pullup resistors but their package is 0402. I prefer not to if there is another way so **I'm wondering if I could (somehow) route the I2C3 to I2C1 in software?** I2C1 clock and data are routed to a connector on the board so they're easily accessible.  This sounds like wishful thinking but ... I'm new to this fancy 32-bit MCU ... LOL. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not the problem you are having now, but once you get it working, make sure you mutex access to I2C3.  I assume that at some point both the touch screen and CODEC will want access to I2C3 at the same time, which will cause major problems if a mutex is not used.  Most sample drivers I have seen do not include a way to provide exclusive access to their peripherals.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be a problem. I expect the touch screen to generate I2C traffic only when I touch the screen and the WM8994 should only access the I2C when needs to change settings. Actual audio data is transfer via I2S/SAI to the WM8994. I'll know more when I connect the scope though. Thanks.

Comment: There is no such option, but input buffer on GPIO pin still work when routed to the I2C peripheral. Depending on your firmware design, you have two options. If your program use standard execution main loop and all jobs are executed qucikly, you can just mirror value to the different port in that loop. If you do not have such loop or your executions are long, you need to use timer, configure it with high priority interrupt and high interrupt generation frequency and in the interrupt handler you can mirror GPIO values `HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0, HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace I2C3 with I2C1, that's pretty easy: configure the I2C1 peripheral, and then replace all the `hi2c3` handles with `hi2c1` handles. However, this won't help with debug, because there won't be any slave devices on the bus. No slave devices means no ACKs, which means you won't get much further than sending the address before the bus will error out.

Ok, what about connecting the two inside the MCU so that they share signals? To my knowlege, this isn't realistic. Possibly doable, but I have no idea how and it'd probably require some nasty hacking and an arcane knowledge of the STM32. At any rate, I'd say doing a bit of annoying soldering to some 0402s is probably easier and more time-efficient.

Looking at [the schematic](https://www.st.com/resource/en/schematic_pack/mb1191-f746ngh6-c03-schematic.pdf), it might be easier to remove R83 and R76 (2x zero-ohm resistors on the I2C bus near the audio CODEC) and then solder-blob over the 0402 footprint, which would give you more room to solder your wire on. That's easier than having to solder a wire directly onto a single pad of an 0402 as you'd have to do with the pullups.